# How to update the form input field with a name attribute

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-forms

```
<Input
   label="Retail price"
   editMode
   name="retail_price"
   rules={[{ required: true, message: validationRequiredText('retail price') }]}
   type="number"
   min={1}
/>
```

In this how can I update and Set the form values using the name="retail_price"?

I tried on other answers on google but didn't get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

To set the value by name you can use the `useForm` hook:

```js
const [form] = Form.useForm();
    
const onSubmit = () => {
  form.setFieldsValue({ retail_price: '200000' });
}

<Button type="primary" onClick={onSubmit}>submit example</Button>

<Form form={form}>
  <Form.Item name="retail_price" label="Retail price" rules={[{ required: true, message: validationRequiredText('retail price') }]}>
    <Input editMode type="number" min={1} />
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Is there any specific documentation where I can learn about useForm()? Because I am a bit new to React I am still drifting around.

Comment: @rasifsahl useform() is an attribute of antd, you can see in the following link https://ant.design/components/form#formuseform

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers support native querySelectorAll so you can do:

document.querySelectorAll('[name="retail_price"]');

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is best to **NOT** use the `document` API in React.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice this question was tagged in React.

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-hook-form library to manage values of the input. here is offical [documention](https://react-hook-form.com/)

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function FormValidation() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      >
          <Input
            placeholder="Retail price"
            type="text"
            {...register("retail_price"}
          />
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In my opinion I wouldn't install another dependency unless needed. Ant design has a "native" method to handle this kinda of operation.

Comment: cant I achieve this only with antd without installing another dependency?